# Spring Integration - file:inbound-channel-adapter - remove original file

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a file:inbound-channel-adapter that polls a directory for files and then sends it via SFTP to a server. After it's uploaded (which works fine), the original file needs to be deleted; how do I delete the original file after it's uploaded?
In file:outbound-channel-adapter, there's a property I can set to autodelete the file.

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="incomingFiles"      
    channel="myFiles"       
    directory="file:/tmp/kots">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="myFiles"/>

....

<sftp:outbound-channel-adapter 
    id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
    channel="myFiles"
    charset="UTF-8"     
    remote-directory="/tmp/testing"     
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Transaction Synchronization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#transaction-synchronization) is for you:

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="incomingFiles"      
    channel="myFiles"       
    directory="file:/tmp/kots">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="1000">
         <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" synchronization-factory="syncFactory" />
    </int:poller>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>


<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
    <int:after-commit expression="payload.delete()" channel="nullChannel"/>
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>
```

Where `transactionManager` might be [`org.springframework.integration.transaction.PseudoTransactionManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#pseudo-transactions) from out of the box.

Comment: Or, use an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` [the retry-and-more sample here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/intermediate/retry-and-more/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/expression-advice-context.xml) uses that technique to delete the file on success or rename it on failure with an ftp outbound adapter.

Comment: Spring Integration is amazing!! Thanks Gary and Artem, that's exactly what I've been looking for!